# Submit button isn't triggering form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-mobile

I have this  html form for which the submit button has some weird behavior.

When I click the Submit button it stays depressed, but it does not submit the form. However, if the form is submitted by other means, say pressing `Enter` on the keyboard, or `GO` on Mobile Safari (iDevice), everything works fine. I am using jQuery mobile btw.

Can anyone see why this might be the case?

### HTML

```
<div class='login' id='login'>
    <div class='login-header'>Please Login</div>
    <div class='alert-error' id='login-error' style='display:none;'>
      Please check your username and password and try again.
    </div>

    <form id='login_form'>
      <br>
      <p class='label'>Username</p>
      <input type='text' name='username'>
      <p class ='label'>Password</p>
      <input type='password' name='password'>
      <button type='submit' data-theme='a' id='login-button'>Login</button> 
    </form>
  </div>
```

### JS

```
$('#login_form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        var serializedFormData = $(this).serialize();

        // blah blah ajax form submit
        });
    });
```

## EDIT

It seems like I was able to solve my problem by switching the following lines:

```
<button type='submit' data-theme='a' id='login-button'>Login</button>
```

with

```
<input type='submit' value='Submit'>.
```

Reputation remains to be awarded to anyone who knows why this worked.

Comment: No, the button tag is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing e.preventDefault(); and see if the button is working.

Comment: Nope, in fact this causes the form to break.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  $('#login_button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var serializedFormData = $('#login_form').serialize();

    // blah blah ajax form submit
    });
});
```

This is how I submit my forms using ajax, pressing return still works as expected

Answer (score -2):

There's no `<button type="submit">Submit me</button>`.

Submit button should actually be an `input` tag with `type="submit"`

Comment: This is expressly wrong. There is a <button type="submit">. See http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/button

Comment: Ye, your link seemes valid. This doesn't answer, why it works like it is wrong, anyway.